# Semantic-UI grid inside pusher and fixed menu

Tags: html, semantic-ui

I want to have a sidebar, fixed top menu and a pusher. But something I do wrong, see this https://jsfiddle.net/mpugach/wg4kc6pp/

```
<body>
    <div id="sidebar" class="inverted left inline vertical orange menu ui sidebar">
        <a class="item">Item 1</a>
        <a class="item">Item 2</a>
        <a class="item">Item 3</a>
    </div>

    <div class="ui inverted huge orange borderless fixed fluid menu">
        <button class="ui button header item" id="toggler">
            Toggle
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="ui grid pusher">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column"> <!-- end of layout -->

                <div class="ui grid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <h1 class="ui huge header">
                              Welcome header
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                          some other text 1
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                          some other text 2
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                          some other text 3
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                          some other text 4
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Is it possible to have the pushed content which is not hidden under top menu? Without additional CSS I mean, just Semantic-UI markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another working solution https://jsfiddle.net/tpg714eh/18/

The structure is the same, however, there is additional css which rewrites Semantic UI.

```
.ui.grid {
  margin-top:0em!important;
}

.ui.pusher {
  margin-top: 2.85714em!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to place menu into the pusher. Also you should remove **fixed** from menu and set border-radius to 0. Here is example: https://jsfiddle.net/tpg714eh/1/

```
<body>
    <div id="sidebar" class="inverted left inline vertical orange menu ui sidebar">
        <a class="item">Item 1</a>
        <a class="item">Item 2</a>
        <a class="item">Item 3</a>
    </div>

    <div class="ui pusher">

    <div class="ui inverted huge borderless orange menu" style="border-radius:0px;">
        <button class="ui button header item" id="toggler">
            Toggle
        </button>
    </div>

      <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column"> <!-- end of layout -->

                <div class="ui grid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <h1 class="ui huge header">
                              Welcome header
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                          some other text 1
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                          some other text 2
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                          some other text 3
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                          some other text 4
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you @alexander-tyapkov, but in this case the menu does not stick to top so it can be scrolled away

Comment: @mpugach yes, that is true. The problem goes from incorrect calculation of padding and margin for ui grid. You can try to rewrite them manually, but it won't be solution without additional css.